Does TeamViewer give a notification about a terminated session if the PC was turned off or rebooted from this program?
It is known that the program informs the managed PC about the end of the session. But when the computer shuts down or restarts from TeamViewer, does the program (at its next launch) make it clear that the PC was turned off or rebooted from it?. Or will this information only be in the logs and TeamViewer will not give you any notes?.

To TeamViewer the machine would have just lost connection.
